# custom actionfilter sending formcollection problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

not sure if this is possible or if i am down the wrong road.

i am wanting to use an attribute to clean out single quotes from my form posted data
(this will be changed, but single quotes is a good example)

i have created the actionFilter as below:

```
public class RemoveSingleQuotesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public NameValueCollection collection { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            collection.Set(
                collection.GetKey(i),
                collection.GetValues(i).ToString().Replace("'","`")
                );
        }
    }
}
```

now this is where i get stuck:

when i type [RemoveSingleQuotes()]   in brackets i only get [Int Order] as the intelisense
and not formcollection/Namevaluecollection

and also how do i pass a collection anyway ?????

is this even possible or am i just creating some mad sh*t up here ????

thanks

Comment: i did try this
[RemoveSingleQuotes(collection=FormCollection)]

but get error that class is not valid at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access formvalues in the filter by filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Form. Anyway it would be easier to build a custom modelbinder that strips of unwanted characters.

That way you can still work with the a bound Model. Your solution will lead to a changed Formcollection, but an unchanged Model. You could call UpdateModel after your changes, but it is still is not a good solution.

**EDIT**

```
public class CustomModelBinder :  DefaultModelBinder {
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) {
    if(propertyDescriptor.Name == "PropertyWithCharactersIneedToReplace") {
        MethodThatReplacesCharacters();
        return;
    }

    base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
}
```

**EDIT 1**
I would apply the ModelBinder this way:

```
public ActionResult UpdateSomeObject([ModelBinder(typeof(NiceModelBinder))]SomeViewModelType model)
```

Comment: my model is subsonic, and i update the .tt files every time a new bug or feature is added... to go your route i would have to alter my TT files every time i wanted my model to do the work i want it to carry out.... so i figure a filter i can write once to do all the procedures i would carry out on a string. i was hopeing here the filter is executed first, so then my formcollection IS then ready to bind as this comes afterwords right ????  unless i have the wrong end of the stick, then please elaborate?  thanks for your comments

Comment: have been thinking the custom model idea is good i see where your going... however is this better?  i would have to create a model binder for each class i have and would have to keep remebering to build a new one everytime i get a new table, if this was to happen! and would a default modelbinder overwrite any subsonic model binders ????

Comment: Hopefully you can work with one Modelbinder for all your classes.
I would try to stay with the Defaultbinder and replace only some parts. The main point is realy where you work: In BindModel or BinProperty. See the edited post.

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmm  nice, but the reason i said about seperate for each is that you have to declare a model binder for typeof  within your global.asax like so: ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(Customer)] =
        new CustomerBinder();
so if you have the patience still!  how would you instantiate the above code?

Comment: I would set the ModelBinder at the action. (see edited code) There is no way I know to apply a ModelBinder to all types.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you work with filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form instead of passing it to the filter? As far as I understand this is the collection that you need.

Comment: yeah i did try to pull httpcontext.current.request.form, but i think i had no .form available but will try again., in this case though do i just pass nothing to the filter ????